# Copy a file to source folder on OneDrive using OneDrive API

Tags: onedrive

I tried to copy a file on OneDrive:

1. Request:

   ```
   POST https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/onedrive_test/foo/bar/a.txt:/action.copy
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 84
   Accept: */*
   Authorization: Bearer Ew...
   Prefer: respond-async
   User-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/3.4.4 Windows/7

   b'{"parentReference": {"path": "/drive/root:/onedrive_test/foo/bar"}, "name": "b.txt"}'
   ```
2. Response: 202 Accepted
3. Request:

   ```
   GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/monitor/4sT2gLAWdXVK7EdkDM7k24ObcUFTzScBof3T80HbmKfVHPnUCDK4fWe01ttH9...
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Connection: keep-alive
   Accept: */*
   Authorization: Bearer Ew...
   User-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/3.4.4 Windows/7

   None
   ```
4. Response: 500 Internal server error if copying to the same folder where source file is.

If I use

```
b'{"parentReference": {"path": "/drive/root:/onedrive_test/foo/bar2"}, "name": "b.txt"}'
```

or

```
b'{"parentReference": {"path": "/drive/root:/onedrive_test/foo"}, "name": "b.txt"}'
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue with OneDrive Consumer - I'll respond to this answer with a comment once it is resolved.

Comment: This issues should now be resolved - sorry for the inconvenience!